# How to use the case-sensitive for MySQL password field?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I have user login but user can login with case-insensitive way Means if your password is 'test' then user able to login with 'TEST' password.
I want to avoid the such type authentication on my password field.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to use the [binary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) keyword in your query use:

```
SELECT /*fields*/ FROM table WHERE /* where clause */ BINARY password = "userpassword"
```

OR

use the [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) in your PHP code:

You can use this also if you store hashed or encrypted password which I recommend.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are storing passwords in clear. That's not only pretty insecure, it's also unnecessary in most situations. My advice is to store passwords in two columns, e.g.:

```
password_salt VARCHAR(16)
password_hash VARCHAR(40)
```

Before storing a new password, take the password provided by the user (`$clear_password`), create a random string (`$salt`) and use both to create a hash (`sha1sum($salt . $clear_password`). Store both the salt and the hash and discard the clear password.

To validate a password, retrieve the stored salt for the given user, generate the hash and see if it matches with the hash in DB.

This technique is called [salted passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response its good idea for security risk

Comment: @SKu Please read this first - http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/. Using sha1 is not enough.

Comment: good for security but does not have to do anything with the question no?

Comment: @Joel - My answer removes the need for binary matching.